# CSS font-size clamp() doesn't work in Safari

Tags: safari

```
font-size:clamp(20pt,8vmin,40pt)
```

Is not resizing text in Safari 13.1 (mac OS) but is working in Chrome

Here is an example
https://codepen.io/sfpx/pen/ExPMZVb
If you resize the result part vertically you will see the font size decreasing in Chrome but not in Safari.

How could I achieve the same result in Safari ?
Let's say I want the font to be 8vmin but a max of 40pt and a min of 20pt.
I tried min , clamp and calc without success in Safari

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having this problem in Safari 13.1 still

Comment: I had  exactly the same issue. Simply updating safair browser to 15.4 solved this problem.